# Split Strings in Half (Word-Aware) with Swift

Tags: swift

Trying to figure out how to split a string in half using Swift. Basically given a string "Today I am in Moscow and tomorrow I will be in New York"
This string has 13 words. I would like to generate 2 "close in length" strings: "Today I am in Moscow and tomorrow" and "tomorrow I will be in New York"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Break the words into an array, then take the two halves of it:

```
let str = "Today I am in Moscow and tomorrow I will be in New York"
let words = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

let halfLength = words.count / 2
let firstHalf = words[0..<halfLength].joinWithSeparator(" ")
let secondHalf = words[halfLength..<words.count].joinWithSeparator(" ")

print(firstHalf)
print(secondHalf)
```

Adjust `halfLength` to your likings.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5.0

I've converted the good Code Different answer's in a useful extension:

```
extension String {
   func splitStringInHalf()->(firstHalf:String,secondHalf:String) {
        let words = self.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let halfLength = words.count / 2
        let firstHalf = words[0..<halfLength].joined(separator: " ")
        let secondHalf = words[halfLength..<words.count].joined(separator: " ")
        return (firstHalf:firstHalf,secondHalf:secondHalf)
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**:

```
let str = "Today I am in Moscow and tomorrow I will be in New York".splitStringInHalf()
print(str.firstHalf)
print(str.secondHalf)
```

Answer (score 1):

**If anyone still looking for a simple way**

> In Swift 4 and above: you can just insert a `chara` in the middle of the string and then do a `split(separator:`

```swift
    var str = "Hello, playground"

    let halfLength = str.count / 2

    let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: halfLength)
    str.insert("-", at: index)
    let result = str.split(separator: "-")
```

for more info about String.Index: [Find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676940/6211514)

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 5+ from the above accepted answer.

```
let str = "Today I am in Moscow and tomorrow I will be in New York"
let words = str.components(separatedBy: " ")

let halfLength = words.count / 2
let firstHalf = words[0..<halfLength].joined(separator: " ")
let secondHalf = words[halfLength..<words.count].joined(separator: " ")

print(firstHalf)
print(secondHalf)
```