# How does String.Index work in Swift

Tags: swift, string, indexing

I've been updating some of my old code and answers with Swift 3 but when I got to Swift Strings and Indexing it has been a pain to understand things.

Specifically I was trying the following:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let prefixRange = str.startIndex..<str.startIndex.advancedBy(5) // error
```

where the second line was giving me the following error

> 'advancedBy' is unavailable: To advance an index by n steps call 'index(_:offsetBy:)' on the CharacterView instance that produced the index.

I see that `String` has the following methods.

```
str.index(after: String.Index)
str.index(before: String.Index)
str.index(String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance)
str.index(String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance, limitedBy: String.Index)
```

These were really confusing me at first so I started playing around with them until I understood them. I am adding an answer below to show how they are used.

Answer (score 382, accepted):

[image]

All of the following examples use

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
```

## `startIndex` and `endIndex`

- `startIndex` is the index of the first character
- `endIndex` is the index *after* the last character.

Example

```
// character
str[str.startIndex] // H
str[str.endIndex]   // error: after last character

// range
let range = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex
str[range]  // "Hello, playground"
```

With Swift 4's [one-sided ranges](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html), the range can be simplified to one of the following forms.

```
let range = str.startIndex...
let range = ..<str.endIndex
```

I will use the full form in the follow examples for the sake of clarity, but for the sake of readability, you will probably want to use the one-sided ranges in your code.

## `after`

As in: `index(after: String.Index)`

- `after` refers to the index of the character directly after the given index.

Examples

```
// character
let index = str.index(after: str.startIndex)
str[index]  // "e"

// range
let range = str.index(after: str.startIndex)..<str.endIndex
str[range]  // "ello, playground"
```

## `before`

As in: `index(before: String.Index)`

- `before` refers to the index of the character directly before the given index.

Examples

```
// character
let index = str.index(before: str.endIndex)
str[index]  // d

// range
let range = str.startIndex..<str.index(before: str.endIndex)
str[range]  // Hello, playgroun
```

## `offsetBy`

As in: `index(String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance)`

- The `offsetBy` value can be positive or negative and starts from the given index. Although it is of the type `String.IndexDistance`, you can give it an `Int`.

Examples

```
// character
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
str[index]  // p

// range
let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
let end = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -6)
let range = start..<end
str[range]  // play
```

## `limitedBy`

As in: `index(String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance, limitedBy: String.Index)`

- The `limitedBy` is useful for making sure that the offset does not cause the index to go out of bounds. It is a bounding index. Since it is possible for the offset to exceed the limit, this method returns an Optional. It returns `nil` if the index is out of bounds.

Example

```
// character
if let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7, limitedBy: str.endIndex) {
    str[index]  // p
}
```

If the offset had been `77` instead of `7`, then the `if` statement would have been skipped.

## Why is String.Index needed?

It would be *much* easier to use an `Int` index for Strings. The reason that you have to create a new `String.Index` for every String is that Characters in Swift are not all the same length under the hood. A single Swift Character might be composed of one, two, or even more Unicode code points. Thus each unique String must calculate the indexes of its Characters.

It is possible to hide this complexity behind an Int index extension, but I am reluctant to do so. It is good to be reminded of what is actually happening.

Comment: Why would `startIndex` be anything else than 0?

Comment: @RoboRobok: Because Swift works with Unicode characters, which are made of "grapheme clusters", Swift doesn't use integers to represent index locations. Let's say your first character is an `é`. It is actually made of the `e` plus a `\u{301}` Unicode representation. If you used an index of zero, you would get either the `e` or the accent ("grave") character, not the entire cluster that makes up the  `é`. Using the `startIndex` ensures you'll get the entire grapheme cluster for any character.

Comment: In Swift 4.0 each Unicode characters are counted by 1.                                             Eg: "‍".count // Now: 1, Before: 2

Comment: How does one construct a `String.Index` from an integer, other than building a dummy string and using the `.index` method on it? I don't know if I'm missing something, but the docs don't say anything.

Comment: @sudo, you have to be a little careful when constructing a `String.Index` with an integer because each Swift `Character` does not necessarily equal the same thing you mean with an integer. That said, you can pass an integer into the `offsetBy` parameter to create a `String.Index`. If you don't have a `String`, though, then you can't construct a `String.Index` (because Swift can only calculate the index if it knows what the previous characters in the string are). If you change the string then you must recalculate the index. You can't use the same `String.Index` on two different strings.

Comment: @Suragch Thanks for the explanation. I've read up on how Swift handles characters, but it still seems odd that you can't create a `String.Index` to represent the i-th character in some string, whatever string you choose. For example, I'm running into this when handling server API responses that include integers I'm supposed to interpret as a character range.

Comment: @Suragch Please, how string.index(before: String.Index) internally works? Does it iterate backwards in the string per 2 bytes (UTF-16), trying to compose extended grapheme cluster with the next scalar, and stop when composing extended grapheme cluster is not possible? Then to return the index BEFORE the current Unicode char (string index). Or is there any smarter algorithm?

Comment: @MichaelBernat, I'm not sure. I couldn't find it in the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift). Someone else can add the link if they can find it.

Comment: I actually noted this link because of your good explanation. I cant figure out though how to use the lastIndex() because I actually want to get the last index + 1 (next character) which the after: is useful for. But I am having a hard time what the right combination is when using those 2. What i want is like in Java lastIndexOf("/") + 1

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this question and all the info with it. I have something in mind that's kind of a question and an answer when it comes to String.Index.

I'm trying to see if there is an O(1) way to access a Substring (or Character) inside a String because string.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1) is O(n) speed if you look at the definition of index function. Of course we can do something like:

```
let characterArray = Array(string)
```

then access any position in the characterArray however SPACE complexity of this is `n` = length of string, O(n) so it's kind of a waste of space.

I was looking at Swift.String documentation in Xcode and there is a frozen public struct called `Index`. We can initialize is as:

```
let index = String.Index(encodedOffset: 0)
```

Then simply access or print any index in our String object as such:

```
print(string[index])
```

*Note: be careful not to go out of bounds`*

This works and that's great but what is the run-time and space complexity of doing it this way? Is it any better?

Comment: `String.Index(encodedOffset: 0)` gives you the index based on a UTF-16 encoding - so it works in O(1) on the assumption that your chars are all UTF-16. It was deprecated in Swift 5 and replaced with the more explicit (String.Index(utf16Offset: l, in: s)). In my opinion this should have been a question rather than an answer e.g. "What does String.Index(encodedOffset: 0) do and why its runtime is O(1)?"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the complexity of these functions, you can use this extension:

```
let str = " Hello"
str[0] //
```

```
extension String {
    subscript(_ index: Int) -> Character? {
        guard index >= 0, index < self.count else {
            return nil
        }

        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea! One thing though, it seems to me, this subscript's runtime is already O(n) because of the guard index < self.count you have. Count is O(n) runtime.

Answer (score -2):

```
func change(string: inout String) {

    var character: Character = .normal

    enum Character {
        case space
        case newLine
        case normal
    }

    for i in stride(from: string.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
        // first get index
        let index: String.Index?
        if i != 0 {
            index = string.index(after: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: i - 1))
        } else {
            index = string.startIndex
        }

        if string[index!] == "\n" {

            if character != .normal {

                if character == .newLine {
                    string.remove(at: index!)
                } else if character == .space {
                    let number = string.index(after: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: i))
                    if string[number] == " " {
                        string.remove(at: number)
                    }
                    character = .newLine
                }

            } else {
                character = .newLine
            }

        } else if string[index!] == " " {

            if character != .normal {

                string.remove(at: index!)

            } else {
                character = .space
            }

        } else {

            character = .normal

        }

    }

    // startIndex
    guard string.count > 0 else { return }
    if string[string.startIndex] == "\n" || string[string.startIndex] == " " {
        string.remove(at: string.startIndex)
    }

    // endIndex - here is a little more complicated!
    guard string.count > 0 else { return }
    let index = string.index(before: string.endIndex)
    if string[index] == "\n" || string[index] == " " {
        string.remove(at: index)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -8):

Create a UITextView inside of a tableViewController. I used function: textViewDidChange and then checked for return-key-input.
then if it detected return-key-input, delete the input of return key and dismiss keyboard.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    if textView.text.contains("\n"){
        textView.text.remove(at: textView.text.index(before: textView.text.endIndex))
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```