# String may not be indexed with int

Tags: ios, swift3

I get error in the last line when I try to set `label1` to the first letter of `string`, using latest version of Swift. How to solve this issue?

```
let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
let name1 = "" + preferences.string(forKey: "name")!
let name2 = name1
label1.text = name2.substring(from: 0)
```

Comment: See [How does String.Index work in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3) and [How does String substring work in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 11):

That's because `substring` method accepts `String.Index` instead of plain `Int`. Try this instead:

```
let index = name2.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 0) //replace 0 with index to start from
label.text = name2.substring(from: index)
```

Answer (score 1):

*the first letter of the string* in Swift 3 is

```
label1.text = String(name2[name2.startIndex])
```

String could not be indexed by `Int` already in Swift 2

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for an Index, not an Int.

```
let str = "string"
print(str.substring(from: str.startIndex))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of functions that make it more objective-c like

```
func substringOfString(_ s: String, toIndex anIndex: Int) -> String
{
    return s.substring(to: s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: anIndex))
}


func substringOfString(_ s: String, fromIndex anIndex: Int) -> String
{
   return s.substring(from: s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: anIndex))
}


//examples
let str = "Swift's String implementation is completely and utterly irritating"
let newstr = substringOfString(str, fromIndex: 30) // is completely and utterly irritating
let anotherStr = substringOfString(str, toIndex: 14) // Swift's String
let thisString = substringOfString(anotherStr, toIndex: 5) // Swift
```