# Swift - sum range.location and range.length

Tags: swift, string, substring

I have following Obj-c statement:

```
string = [string substringFromIndex:(range.location + range.length)];
```

What it's Swift equivalent?

Comment: Couldn't you just have looked this up? This doesn't seem like a hard conversion at all...

Comment: Check this link for detail -
[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3)

Comment: @BenjaminLowry, Having multiple range types in Swift, and no Xcode help, it is a hard conversion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [substring(from:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642883-substring):

```
var string = "Hello World"

string = string.substring(from: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 6))

print(string) // "World"
```

Also, you might want to use [substring(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1643184-substring):

```
let hello = string.substring(to: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))

print(hello) // "Hello"
```

For more information about `String.Index`, check this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3).

Comment: So the answer is "replace `range.length` with `6`"?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use substring:

```
let string = "abcdefghijklm"
let startPoint = 2
let length = 5

let startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: startPoint)
let endIndex = string.index(startIndex, offsetBy: length)

let result = string[startIndex ..< endIndex]
print(result)         // cdefg
```