# Swift, handle Arrays and Datatypes (Split String from String)

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I just started with Swift a few days ago and I am struggling with all the different Datatypes...

Lets say we do this:

```
var myarray = ["justin", "steve", "peter"]
var newString = myarray[2]
```

so why I cant now print just the "p" from "peter"?

```
print(newString[0])
```

---> gives me an error:

`"'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int"`

in this topic:
[[Get nth character of a string in Swift programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language][3])

it says: 
*"Note that you can't ever use an index (or range) created from one string to another string"*

But I cant imagine, that there isn't way to handle it...

Because When I do this:

```
var myarray = ["justin", "steve", "p.e.t.e.r"]
var newString = myarray[2]
let a : [String] = newString.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
print(a[2])
```

- then it works. It prints (in this case) "t".

**So how I can split it "SeparatedByString" 'Nothing'?**

Im sure to solve this will help me also at many other problems.
I hope I postet the question in the way it should be done.

Thank you for any solution or tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance method [`componentsSeparatedByString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components) applied to a `String` instance yields an *array of `String` instances*, namely `[String]`. The elements of an array can be indexed in the classic Java/C++ fashion (`let thirdElement = array[2]`).

If you'd like to split your `String` instance (`"peter"`) into an array of single character `String` instances, you can make use of the `CharacterView` property of a `String` instance, and thereafter map each single `Character` in the `CharacterView` back to a single-character `String` instance

```
let str = "peter"
let strArray = str.characters.map(String.init(_:)) // ["p", "e", "t", "e", "r"]
let thirdElement = strArray[2] // t
```

This is quite roundabout way though (`String -> CharacterView -> [String] -> String`), and you're most likely better off simply looking at the excellent answer (covering direct `String` indexing) in the dupe thread dug up by @Hamish:

- [How does String.Index work in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3)

The possible corner case where the above could be applicable, as pointed out by Hamish below, is if you very frequently need access to characters in the `String` at specific indices, and like to make use of the O(1) random access available to arrays (more so applicable if you are working with immutable `String`:s, such that the corresponding `String` array only needs to be generated once for each immutable `String` instance).

Comment: This is a good approach if you need to *frequently* access the characters at a given index though, without having to do a linear walk for each access :)

Comment: Thank you. :) it gives me 2 Errors ("Expected ',' separator"

"Expected expression in list of expressions") but it's maybe a Problem of my Swift version (2.1.1). I'll also check the linked thread. Thanks, helped me to not rage! :D

Comment: @Hamish that's true! I don't really know what I _really_ think of the `.map(String.init(_:))` variation though, as compared to `.map { String($0) }`, but hey, why not :D

Comment: @scopaest replace the 2nd line in the snippet above with `let strArray = str.characters.map { String($0) }` and it might work for Swift 2.1 (tested and working for Swift 2.2).

Comment: @dfri Yeah, I usually go back to using a closure expression when it gets to the point where you have to disambiguate the `init` with `(_:)`, but I guess it's a matter of preference :)

Comment: @Hamish I also prefer the closure for (imo) better semantics, but I'm uncertain if the closure approach could have a minimal (/negligible :) extra overhead as compared to directly supplying an initializer-function-reference. I've never benchmarked this, and the compiler _should_ optimize the former to the latter, but I can't really say.

Comment: @dfri yea, it works! thank you! :D

Comment: @dfri The cost difference should indeed be negligible. Without optimisations, I would say that the closure expression should actually be *slightly* faster. The reasoning for this is that `String.init(_:)` cannot be passed directly into `map(_:)` – it first has to be partially applied with the metatype `String.self`, which will create a new closure on the heap. The closure expression on the other hand is stored statically, so doesn't incur an allocation cost.

Comment: But with optimisations, the compiler can perform all sorts of clever specialisations and inlinings, so it's a lot harder to reason with (but from a quick benchmark, it appears the closure expression still wins).

Comment: @Hamish very instructive, thanks! My own speculation was too heavily C++ inspired, thinking to compare a lightweight function pointer to a slightly more complex function object (the closure); really good to know that this is not applicable in Swift. Btw, this should be no difference even in case `map` didn't have `@autoclosure`?

Comment: @dfri You can indeed think of it like that, it's just the other way round – in this case, the closure expression is the (more or less) lightweight function pointer (although it may carry a heap-allocated context object around with it to store info about captured values, and may be partially applied itself to capture stuff). `String.init(_:)` on the other hand needs partial applying in this case, so a new closure (function object) is created on the fly (at least for unoptimised builds) to encapsulate the application of `(String.Type) -> (Character) -> String` to `(Character) -> String`.

Comment: And `map` doesn't have `@autoclosure` ;)

Comment: @Hamish I see, thanks for the expansive explanation! Ah yes, mixup `@autoclosure` vs final-argument as trailing closure on my behalf :)

Comment: No problem :) Also if you had a global function with the signature `(Character) -> String` and passed that to `map(_:)` rather than `String.init`, that would also be comparable to passing a simple function pointer to `map(_:)`. Also now that I come to think of it, things get slightly more complex when passing functions to parameters where generics are involved – they are partially applied with a "reabstraction thunk helper" (I believe it's in order to unify the calling conventions of the functions passed). This will incur the cost of a closure allocation, but can be specialised in -O builds.

Comment: Sorry for going on a bit – this is what happens when you go through the emitted SIL :P

Comment: @Hamish no worries at all (the contrary), evey new comment from you here is much appreciated and instructive; I've dug quite deep in the stdlibs myself, but none at all into SIL (& emitted/generated SIL). The latter is apparently also very interesting, will need to look into this myself, inspired and prompted by your nice comments above :) so thanks again!