# Why does swift gives an error when I set the offsetBy value equal to endIndex value in the index(_ , offsetBy , limitedBy) function?

Tags: swift

Here is the code:

1- It's okay when offsetBy is 4 or less

```
    let someString = "hello"

    if let someIndex = someString.index(someString.startIndex, 
                        offsetBy: 4, limitedBy: someString.endIndex){
       someString[someIndex]
    }
    // Prints "o"
```

2- It's okay when offsetBy is 6 or greater

```
    if let someIndex = someString.index(someString.startIndex, 
                        offsetBy: 6, limitedBy: someString.endIndex){
       someString[someIndex]
    }
    // Prints "nil"
```

3- But it gives error when offsetBy is 5

```
    if let someIndex = someString.index(someString.startIndex, 
                        offsetBy: 5, limitedBy: someString.endIndex){
       someString[someIndex]
    }
    // error
```

and the error is:

> error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted,
>   reason:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). The
>   process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use
>   "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression
>   evaluation.

Comment: Compare [How does String.Index work in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39676939/2976878)

Comment: You are using the wrong value for the limit.  `endIndex` is one past the last valid index.  Instead, use `limitedBy: str.index(before: str.endIndex)`.

Comment: @Hamish thanks. I read the link. but limitedBy limits 6 and higher. why not 5?

Comment: @vacawama awesome. now it works and I know the reason.

Comment: Alternatively: `if let someIndex = someString.index(someString.startIndex, offsetBy: 5, limitedBy: someString.endIndex), someIndex != someString.endIndex { ... }` – Note that `str.index(before: str.endIndex` would fail for an empty string.

Comment: @Arashk Because `endIndex` is still a useful index – most commonly used when forming the range `someIndex..<endIndex`. You could also define your own version of `index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)` where the limit is an exclusive upper bound if you feel strongly about it. But really a simpler solution would be just add `, someIndex < someString.endIndex` to the `if` statement.

Comment: @Hamish/MartinR, right you are about the crash for an empty string.  It's a shame they didn't make the API less than the limit.  I notice that many people mistakenly use `endIndex` for the limit.

Comment: @vacawama: But then `if let from = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: 5, limitedBy: s.endIndex), let to = s.index(from, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: s.endIndex)` would not work to get 2 characters at position 5.

Comment: @MartinR/vacawama/Hamish you're right. it's gonna cash for an empty string. what a good experience you have. By the way, what's the solution for that?

Comment: Somebody should write an answer now ... or is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3 good enough as a duplicate?

Comment: I volunteer @Hamish to write the answer since he was the first to engage the OP. :-)

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll get typing... :)

Comment: @MartinR, if the limit were less than, then you'd use `if let from = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: 5, limitedBy: s.endIndex), let to = s.index(from, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: s.endIndex)` and `s[from...to]` to get 2 characters at position 5.

Comment: @vacawama: ... which I do not find intuitive, but I think we can leave it at that :)

Comment: As it is, I find using the limit the way it is implemented now to be similar to when you used to not be able to form ranges like `0...Int.max` because Swift internally used upper limit + 1, and there is not such value for Int.max. Anyway, it is what it is as they say.  And with Swift, it will probably be different in version N+1 anyway.

Comment: hi @Arashk - are you there?  You should "Tick" an answer please.

Comment: @JoeBlow Sorry. I didn't know that. Now, I've learned it.

Comment: hi @Arashk have a great day.  Yeah I believe it gives YOU more points, and, allows you to ask more questions without being moderated so much, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the limit given to `index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)` is an *inclusive* bound for the result. Therefore with

```
let someString = "hello"
```

the index returned by

```
someString.index(someString.startIndex, offsetBy: 5, limitedBy: someString.endIndex)
```

will be `someString.endIndex`, which is a *past the end* index, and therefore not a valid index to subscript the string with.

A simple solution therefore would be to just add a condition to your `if` statement to check that the index you get back isn't the `endIndex`:

```
let someString = "hello"
let offset = 5

if let someIndex = someString.index(someString.startIndex,
                                    offsetBy: offset,
                                    limitedBy: someString.endIndex
                                    ), someIndex != someString.endIndex {
    print(someString[someIndex])
}
```

Or a nicer option would be to use the `CharacterView`'s [`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641719-indices) property in order to get a collection of *valid* indices to subscript with (excluding `endIndex`), and use [`dropFirst(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641742-dropfirst) and [`first`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641697-first) in order to get the index at the given offset:

```
if let index = someString.characters.indices.dropFirst(offset).first {
    print(someString[index])
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `dropFirst(_:)` takes an upper bound of elements to drop, returning an empty subsequence if it's larger than the collection's count, as well as the fact that `first` returns `nil` for an empty collection.

Comment: @Downvoter I respect your right to anonymity, but would welcome any constructive feedback. I take pride in the quality of my answers, and am always looking to improve them :)