# Xcode Playground bug? "fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

With the following code, I get `fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String` in the Console. I don't see where or what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Solution {
  func isValid(_ s: String) -> Bool {
    var dictionary = [Character: Character]()
    dictionary["("] = ")"
    dictionary["{"] = "}"
    dictionary["["] = "]"

    for (i, character) in s.characters.enumerated() {
      if i % 2 == 0 {
        if let idx = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: i + 1, limitedBy: s.endIndex) {
          if dictionary[character] != s[idx] {
            return false
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return true
  }
}

var sol = Solution()
let test = "()[]["
print(sol.isValid(test))
```

Xcode 8.3.2
Swift 3+

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/42958011/2976878 – the `limitedBy:` parameter is an *inclusive* upper bound, so you're trying to subscript the string with its `endIndex` (which is a past the end index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from the expression `s[idx]` when `idx` is too large. The error goes away when you update the calculation of `idx` to:

```
if let idx = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: i + 1, limitedBy: s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)) {
```

or, as kindly suggested by Leo,

```
if let idx = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: i + 1, limitedBy: s.index(before: s.endIndex)) {
```

Comment: `limitedBy: s.index(before: s.endIndex)`