# conversion of code swift 2.3 to swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

```
let subString = self[Range(start: start++, end: endIndex)]
if subString.hasPrefix(other){
    return true
}
```

i have this code in swift 2.3, i used this code as an extension for string value,
xcode converted it as follow

```
let subString = self[((start++) ..< endIndex)]
```

and start giving me error

> Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue String.Index' (aka '@lvalue String.CharacterView.Index')

i don't know now how exactly Xcode want me to write it?

Comment: Compare [How does String.Index work in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39676939/2976878) – you want to do `index(after: start)` (this won't mutate `start`, but you can easily do that by assigning to it on a seperate line).

Comment: @Harmish that helped (y)

Comment: that is what i am doing! i am just saying if i have talk about the same question and i can't comment! then what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 you cannot increment `String.Index` directly by an `Int`.

I don't know exactly how `start` is defined but you could replace `start++` with

```
self.index(start, offsetBy: 1)
```

Comment: @GurjotKalsi Make sure you accept vadian's answer if it worked for you.

Comment: yes i tried it said wait for few minutes! so i am just waiting