# Swift string after specific index

Tags: swift, string

I want to know how to get rest of string after specific character.

I have checked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3)

but have not found answer.

Consider following code:

```
let fullString = "Blue Sky"
let spaceIndex = fullName.index(of: " ")!
```

I know i can get first string before like that:

```
let firstString = fullString[fullString.startIndex..<spaceIndex] // "Blue”
```

But `let firstString = fullString[fullString.startIndex..>spaceIndex] // "Blue”` not work.

What i want is - "Sky". How to get it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677331/1891327

Comment: @ShamasS you dont read my question dont you?

Comment: @ShamasS space is just example. I need to know how to separate after specific character.

Comment: :) You already know how to find the position of a specific character, go through the answer that I posted, it tells you how to get a range.

Comment: @ShamasS in my question i wrote that i didnt found solution in answer you linked.

Comment: Y'all should keep arguing about what's not there rather than actually just posting the answer @Sharmas S. That's a much better use of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can separate the sentence into array of words and get last word. Try this. You can replace " " with any character or string.

```
let fullString = "Blue Sky"
print(fullString.components(separatedBy: " ").last)//Sky
```

**Or**

```
if let index = fullString.firstIndex(of: " ") {
    print(fullString[index...])//Sky
}
```

Answer (score 3):

components(separatedBy:) will split your string into an array of strings enabling you to access the different elements in the array using indexes.

```
 let fullString = "Blue Sky"    
 let splitString = fullString.components(separatedBy: " ")

 print("Part before space: \(splitString[0])") // Part before space: Blue
 print("Part after space: \(splitString[1])") // Part after space: Sky
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operator as `..>` in Swift.

However, you *can* use the `..<` operator, as in `fullString[spaceIndex..<fullString.endIndex]`.

Or, in Swift 4, you can just: `fullString[spaceIndex...]`.

Comment: unfortunatelly it contain "space" character as well. I dont need it.

Comment: Then you can: `fullString[fullString.index(after: spaceIndex)...]`