# String Indexes in swift

Tags: swift

```
let greeting = "Hello World"
greeting[greeting.startIndex]
```

This code will print first character of string "H"

```
let = "Hello World"
greeting.startIndex
greeting.endIndex
```

whats the difference? this thing don't do anything. Even i dont get error for

```
greeting.endIndex
```

of course I am not retrieving string value through subscript syntax but in the Substring topic I found

```
greeting.endIndex
```

it is print only

```
string.index
```

Ok let me explain why I am asking about `string.index` and `greeting.endIndex`

```
let greeting = "Hello_world!"
let index = greeting.index(of: "_") ?? greeting.endIndex
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
// beginning is "Hello"
```

This code is related to substring, I totally understand what is it doing and in second line of code there is Nil-Coalescing Operator and you know what is it for. But what if

```
let greeting = "Hello world!"
let index = greeting.index(of: "_") ?? greeting.endIndex
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
// beginning is "Hello world"
```

If there is no `"_"` in string value means `greeting.index(of: "_")` is `nil` then it should be returns default value `greeting.endIndex` as Nil-Coalescing Operator does right. So why does `greeting.endIndex` returning `"Hello world!"

Comment: None of your code prints anything. Please show your *actual* code.

Comment: ok Let me clear first why I ask this question.
how to type code in comments?

Comment: In your last example, `index` becomes `greeting.endIndex`, and therefore `greeting[..<index]` becomes the entire string. What is unclear about that?

Comment: Yeah `greeting[..<index]` means entire string except `greeting.endIndex` postion because `endIndex` is the position after the last character of the string. But when I print `greeting.endIndex` it says its `String.index`

Comment: Yeah `greeting[..<index]` means entire string except `greeting.endIndex` postion because `endIndex` is the position after the last character of the string. But to access `endIndex` position  `greeting[greeting.endIndex]` is the snytax. Why cant i use that. I am getting error message.
Error : `Cannot convert value of type 'Character' to expected argument type 'String.Index'`

Comment: Actual confusion was between character and range. `endIndex` different for character and range. This [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3) help me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you describe `startIndex` return  position of the first character in a nonempty string and the `endIndex` return the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.

Also in version 4 of the Swift. String is represented as Collection.

So when you do:

```
greeting[greeting.startIndex]
```

You ask `greeting` string to return element in the first position that is "H"

Comment: `greeting[greeting.endIndex]` does not return the position of the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does nothing. This code however

```
let greeting = "Hello"

print(greeting[greeting.startIndex]) // Prints 'H'
print(greeting[greeting.endIndex])
```

Causes a fatal error because `greeting.endIndex` actually "points" to just after the end of the String, so the last statement is an array bounds violation.

Comment: @MartinR `greeting[greeting.endIndex]` also causes a fatal error when typed into a Playground

Comment: @MartinR `greeting.endIndex` in a Playground just says (effectively) this is a `String.Index`

Comment: Sure. I am just referring to *"Your code does nothing"*. In a Playground, the expression will be evaluated and the results printed to the output window.

Comment: hey can you please tell me how to add linebrake while typing code in comments. so I can explain.

Comment: @Tanzz I've been on here for 6 years, have a rep of over 68k and I do not know how to put line breaks in code in comments :-)

Comment: @Tanzz: Put all relevant information into the question, not in comments.

Comment: @Martin R hey i put all the information in question. Can you please check it again? I hope it will help to understand why i was confuse about `greeting.endIndex`

Comment: is `greeting.endIndex` used in that example like `prefix(_:)` method ?
`prefix(_:)` Returns a subsequence, up to the specified maximum length, containing the initial elements of the collection.If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the collection, the result contains all the elements in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

The `startIndex` is the start of the string. The `endIndex` is the end of the string. You can use these when building ranges or when creating new indexes as an `offsetBy` from one or both of these.

So, for example, if you want a `Substring` that excluded the first and last characters, you could set `fromIndex` to be `startIndex` plus 1 and `toIndex` to be `endIndex` less 1, yielding:

```
let string = "Hello World"
let fromIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let toIndex = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
let substring = string[fromIndex..<toIndex]                // "ello Worl"
```

---

You then ask:

> If there is no `"_"` in string value means `greeting.index(of: "_")` is `nil` then it should be returns default value `greeting.endIndex` as Nil-Coalescing Operator does right. So why does `greeting.endIndex` returning `"Hello world!"

Make sure you don't conflate the `string[index]` syntax (which returns a `Character`) and the `string[..<index]` which returns a `Substring` from the `startIndex` up to `index` (i.e. "return `Substring` of everything up to `index`"):

```
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
```

This partially bound range is just short-hand for:

```
let beginning = greeting[greeting.startIndex..<index]
```

So, when you default `index` to the `greeting.endIndex`, that's like saying you want a substring that is, effectively, the whole string:

```
let beginning = greeting[greeting.startIndex..<greeting.endIndex]
```

So, that's why the syntax presented in your question, `greeting[..<index]`, returns the whole string if `_` was not found and it used `endIndex`.

---

As an aside, if you wanted different behavior, namely for it to return an empty substring if the `_` is not found, you could do the following:

```
let index = greeting.index(of: "_") ?? greeting.startIndex
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
```

Or, if you think that's a little too cute, just adopt standard safe unwrapping patterns, e.g.:

```
guard let index = greeting.index(of: "_") else {
    // handle unfound _ here
}
let beginning = greeting[..<index]
```

Comment: can you please revisit the question again?

Comment: @Tanzz - Did this answer your question?