# Swift 4: Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>'

Tags: swift, range, substring

So I have this swift code:

```
func didReceiveResponse(response:String) {
  ...
  let substr = response[11...]
```

By my interpretation, `substr` should be a [Substring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring) referencing all characters after index 11 in the response string.

What actually happens is this compiler error:

`Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>'`

This seems like it should be obvious, can anyone help please?

Comment: `String` is indexed by `String.Index`, not `Int` – see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/39676939/2976878

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whoops. Seems I needed to just do this:

```
let idx = response.index(response.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)
let substr = response[idx...]
```

Comment: You could also say `let subsets = response.dropFirst(11)` :)