# Swift: String.removeSubrange - HowTo?

Tags: swift

I somehow miss what they want me to do when I want to cut a String in Swift. They told me Swift was "objective". But it rather is "not working". Removing a sub range from a string is explained in the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3018537-removesubrange), which I read. But before I move back to ObjC, let me ask this question: From

```
measurements.removeSubrange(1..<4)
```

I made

```
logString = logString.removeSubrange(logSizeLimit..logString.count)
```

It said `Cannot find operator '..' in scope; did you mean '...'?` I changed it to be `...`. It now tells me:

```
(1.) Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String'
(2.) Instance method 'removeSubrange' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent
```

This is my code:

```
public let logSizeLimit = 40960
public var logString = ""
func senderLoggedMessage(_ message:String) {
    var msg = message + "\n"
    msg += logString
    logString = msg
    if logString.count > logSizeLimit {
        logString = logString.removeSubrange(logSizeLimit ... logString.count) // error line
    }
}
```

Well. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift

Comment: It seems like you don't need `removeSubrange` at all. You can just do `logString = String(logString.prefix(logSizeLimit))`

Comment: Aren't we supposed to use ```removeSubrange``` on a collection? Not sure.

Comment: @Sweeper: Thank you for the advice. But `logString.removeSubrange(logSizeLimit..<logString.count)` also says `Instance method 'removeSubrange' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent`. But the `prefix` thing works for me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `removeSubrange` is a mutating method that returns `Void`. So `logString.removeSubrange(_:)` modifies `logString` in place. It does not return a new `String`. You would have exactly the same sort of problem with the `-[NSMutableString deleteCharactersInRange:]` method in Objective-C.
2. You are trying to use `Int` to index into a `String`'s characters. But Swift `String`s do not use `Int` indices.

   There is a type, `String.Index`, which you can use to index into a `String` with `removeSubrange` and other functions. But I don't recommend it.

   Swift's `String` is very, very careful about handling Unicode properly. So a `String` is not just an array of bytes or of UTF-16 code units as in many other languages. A `String` is a collection of `Character`s, and a `Character` is a “user-perceived character” as discussed in [Unicode Standard Annex #29: Unicode Text Segmentation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

   The `Character` ‘a’ is one code point (U+0061) and one UTF-8 code unit, but the `Character` ‘‍‍‍’ is **seven** code points (U+1f468 U+200d U+1f469 U+200d U+1f467 U+200d U+1f466) and 25 UTF-8 code units.

   Because each `Character` in a `String` may use a different amount of storage, manipulating a `String.Index` is not trivial the way manipulating an `Int` is. You have to use methods on `String` like `index(after:)` and `distance(from:to:)` instead of operators like `+` and `-`.

In my experience, it is much, much easier to slice up a `String` using operations like `.prefix(_:)` and `.drop(while:)`. These operations generally return a `Substring`. So at the end you can use `String.init` to convert the `Substring` back to a `String` if needed.

I would write your function like this:

```
public let logSizeLimit = 40960
public var logString = ""
func senderLoggedMessage(_ message:String) {
    logString = String("\(message)\n\(logString)"
        .prefix(logSizeLimit))
}
```

Comment: This is basically a rather detailed explanation and you got an upvote for it. It is just missing something: In my case the compiler complained about `..`, but the Apple docs say one must use `..`. It makes sense that `String.Index` is not equivalent to `Int`. But if Apple's docs say `measurements.removeSubrange(1..<4)` was correct, how do you actually call that method in real life and real code? How do you create `String.Index`? Let it be some string of unknown length and you want to remove 90% of the characters from the middle of the string (Remaining 5% at start and end each).

Comment: You start with `string.startIndex` or `string.endIndex` and then use other methods like `string.index(_:offsetBy:)`. But again I'd avoid indices and instead say `string.prefix(string.count / 20) + string.suffix(string.count / 20)`.